# CKAN datapusher error 500 datapusher.wsgi cannot be loaded as python module

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, ckan

Im using ckan and want to activate the datapusher plugin. So I followed the few steps on the ckan page. But after the installation I got a 500 error on the port and got this error in the logs:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=536): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=536): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
 web.init()
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

So it seems to be a problem with the datapusher.wsgi
But caused by my tiny knowledge in python and apache I'm not able to solve this problem.

Does someone else experienced this problem and got a workaround for that or knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installed it. In my case was because requirements.txt were not installed correctly at the first time.

I would also suggest to check the configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available/datapusher and by the way see if /var/log/apache2/datapusher.error.log gives any more clue about it.

Be sure that you also have added the configuration of datapusher (ckan.datapusher.url and ckan.site_url) in the .ini file.

Hope it helps to you :)